# How do you change the audio device in using System.Speech.Synthesis

Tags: c#, audio, device, text-to-speech

I'm trying to use System.Speech.Synthesis to play text that is then output over a tapi modem.

SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice() is easy enough to figure out, but I don't want the sound to come out of the speakers.

I think i need to use SetOutputToAudioStream, but I'm not sure how to use it and I can't find any examples ...

I tried changing the default device in the control panel, but that didn't work either :(

Insight anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Does the modem have a .NET api? If it does, check to see how it exposes its input. If it's a stream, you should be able to take the stream and pass it into the SetOutputToAudioStream method, and have your output sent to the device that way.

Comment: What fire.eagle said - it's hard to tell you what you need since you haven't described what the modem side looks like.  SetOutputToAudioStream is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254930/question-speechsynthesizer-setoutputtoaudiostream-audio-format-problem)?  It has a brief example.

Also - if your modem supports TAPI, you should review the samples in the Windows SDK, in particular, the Simple Telephony sample in %windowssdkdir%\Samples\winui\speech\simpletelephony.  This is written in C++, but it demonstrates how to get the audio device ID for the modem and to set the device ID for SAPI's audio stream.

Answer (score -2):

You can change output of text to speech in control panel->speech recognition->text to speech->advanced. Then select "Use this audio output device" and select audio device to output text to speech.

Comment: This is a programming question, asking how to do that action using C#.